# What does mean processing in apache flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm having trouble with the concept of processing in apache Flink. When it comes to processing in apache Flink, what does this process involve? Is there an example for that?

Comment: Removed the tag <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink ships with a bunch of examples, and there several more complete examples in the [online training](https://training.ververica.com).

The basic architecture involves a cluster of stateful processing nodes -- which you might think of, to a first approximation, as a shared key-value store. Live data streams are passing through these nodes. The state held in the cluster is being updated by your business logic in response to these data flows, and their output is being affected by this state.

Typical use cases: ETL, fraud/anomaly detection, ride sharing platforms, logistics management.

Flink can operate at very large scale, with low latency and high throughput. A talk like this one about dynamic pricing at Lyft should help get across the big ideas in the context of a real application: https://www.ververica.com/resources/flink-forward-san-francisco-2019/streaming-your-lyft-ride-prices

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I still didn't understand what it meant to be processed. Suppose I get the data from Instagram and go to Apache Flink. Then it goes into my database. What is my processing on my Instagram data done by Apache Flink?

Comment: Whatever you want. For example, perhaps you use Flink to apply an image classifier to each instagram posting, and store in the database the image URL and a string label indicating whether the posting was a landscape, portrait, group photo, etc.

Comment: For example, can tagging data be done at high speed? Or can data searches be done with Apache Flink and high speed?

Comment: Yes. I've updated my answer to include a link to talk that should be of interest.